# Выпадает ли position absolute из DOM?

Tags: css, вёрстка

Я смотрел ролик про позицинирование в css. Автором была сказана такая мысль, что когда элементу применяется абсолютное позиционирование, то он как бы выпадает из DOM дерева, аналогично как это происходит с display none. Т.е другие элементы его не видят и не реагируют. Так ли это, или это в корне неправильное объяснение? У меня тогда встречный вопрос, почему тогда появляется горизонтальная прокрутка если отодвинуть элемент далеко вправо за границы вьюпорта, он же как сказал автор "выпадает" на странице и должно быть все равно?

И еще небольшой вопросик, почему если отодвинуть элемент вправо за границы, то горизональная прокрутка появляется, а если в лево то нет, насколько далеко не двигали бы? Мне кажется это довольном странно. С right работает таким образом, left совсем наоборот

Comment: position: absolute не выпадает ниоткуда, просто он теряет вес, то есть не влияет на ширину и высоту остальных элементов. Но он всё также подчиняется разметке внешнего элемента с position: relative. А вот насчёт скролла никогда не задумывался, но вопрос интересный)

Comment: "Элемент удаляется из обычного потока документов", не из ДОМ-дерева. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @ЕвгенийЛи т.е правильнее будет сформулировать что при position absolute другие элементы просто перестают замечать абсолютно позиционированный элемент, верно?

Comment: @ksa прочёл статью, т.е правильнее будет сформулировать что при position absolute другие элементы просто перестают замечать абсолютно позиционированный элемент, верно?

Comment: @28Lucky они перестают замечать его физические параметры дающие объём типо ширины и высоты, а его самого они видят точно также как и вы, и всё ещё могут с ним взаимодействовать. Например элемент с position:absolute; перекрывает какой-то другой элемент, но мы можем задать перекрытому элементу "position: relative: z-index: 10;" - задать z-index больше и он будет поверх absolute-ного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю всё дело в направлении "direction: ltr или rtl". Оно задаёт начало слева или справа. Думаю даже у арабов или Евреев например скролл появляется не справа, а слева.

```css
.okno-brauzera {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  display: block;
  background: yellow;
  overflow-x: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.okno-brauzera.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
.element-left {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
}
.element-right {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  right: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="okno-brauzera">
  <div class="element-left"></div>
  <div class="element-right"></div>
</div>

<div class="okno-brauzera rtl">
  <div class="element-left"></div>
  <div class="element-right"></div>
</div>
```